# Get group of data from EntityCollection with LinkEntity

Tags: c#, linq

I have a flat structure of data which I have retrieved with a QueryExpression and LinkEntity (InnerJoin). I have aliased the child with "element"

So my data looks like this:

```
parentIdPK     parentStatus     element.ChildIdPK     element.parentIdFK
1              100              10                    1
1              100              11                    1
1              100              12                    1
2              100              13                    2
2              100              14                    2
3              100              15                    3
3              100              16                    3
3              100              17                    3
```

So bascially I have a Parent/Child structure and I want to push this data into my own classes:

```
public class ExistingProposal
{
   public Guid parentIdPK { get; set; }
   public int parentStatus { get; set; }
   public List<ExistingElement> Elements { get; } = new List<ExistingElement>();
}

public class ExistingElement
{
   public Guid ChildIdPK { get; set; }
   public Guid parentIdFK { get; set; }
}
```

So in general this would lead to have one ExistingProposal with N ExistingGRProposalElement's

Ho can I achieve this in the best way? I have tried with linq but I'm struggling pretty much with this.

What I am trying actually is to group the data with linq:

```
var groups = from a in result.Entities
    orderby a.Attributes["parentId"]
    group a by a.Attributes["parentId"] into g
    select new { g };
```

The problem I have actually is I dont know exactly from where to start to create the needed class structure.

Maybe somebody can point me to the right direction?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried by now?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but, if I understood well the following expression will do the trick for you :

```
var groups = from a in result.Entities
group a by a.Attributes["parentId"] into g
select new ExistingProposal {
    parentIdPK = a.Key,
    parentStatus = (int)a.FirstOrDefault().Attributes["parentStatus"],
    Elements = (from y in g
               select new ExistingElement {
                   ChildIdPK = y.Attributes["element.ChildIdPK"],
                   parentIdFK  = a.Key
               }).ToList()
};
```

1. You'll need to add a setter to your `Elements` property in `ExistingProposal`
2. You don't need to order before grouping
3. You should rename intermediate vars (y, g, a, etc.) to more meaningful ones